# Google Places API queryautocomplete restrictions by country doesn't work

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I am using Google maps in my xamarin forms app and I wanted to restrict the queryautocomplete by country. Following the GoogleMaps Places API docs https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete the optional parameter *components* should do the trick, but it's not working for me.

Looking up KFC while restricted by country let's say TUNISIA (TN) for example.. brings up search results from Germany, France and Indonesia. Even changing the parameters order does nothing. My query results are [here](https://pastebin.com/HyYRjiXy).

The url format I'm using:

```
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"api/place/queryautocomplete/json?" +
                        $"key=MY_KEY" +
                        $"&language=fr" +
                        $"&input={Uri.EscapeUriString("KFC")}" +
                        $"&components=country:TN");
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaking the 2 APIs. Your endpoint is pointing to `/queryautocomplete/` ([**Query Autocomplete**](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/query)), but you are referring to the docs for [**Place Autocomplete**](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete), which endpoint is `/place/autocomplete/`.

With *Place Autocomplete* you can:

> The Place Autocomplete service is a web service that returns place predictions in response to an HTTP request. The request specifies a textual search string and **optional geographic bounds**. The service can be used to provide autocomplete functionality for text-based **geographic searches**, by returning places such as businesses, addresses and **points of interest** as a user types.

With *Query Autocomplete* you can:

> The Query Autocomplete service allows you to add on-the-fly geographic query predictions to your application. **Instead of searching for a specific location**, a user can type in a categorical search, such as "pizza near New York" and the service responds with a list of suggested queries matching the string. As the Query Autocomplete service can match on both full words and substrings, applications can send queries as the user types to provide on-the-fly predictions.

To sum up, the *Places* API can restrict (and it is its job) the queries to a specific region. The *Query* API can't restrict by country (and that's by design).

Comment: Right, I really confused both APIs, thank you for your reply. In my application I am want to display places (points of interest) predictions based on user input let's say selecting a destination to go to, so I suppose what I need is **Place Autocomplete API** but **I am curious whether I can use both APIs simultaneously to make user search even more flexible and accurate however the search results needs to be restricted to a country.**
I might be again confusing both of them but really looking to make my app's prediction on point, you know.

Comment: I'd advise to only use one, depending on how it fits your use case, as these two Places API services are billed separately. Details on the billing is [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing)